# Why the application does not see the Roles in Spring Security (Forbidden)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, roles

There is a `Spring-MVC` project in which there are three types of users: `Customer`, `Admin`, `Cook`. All of them are inherited from the class `User`. Roles are created without `ENUM`, simply through **static String constants** (shown in the `User` class). After I added `Spring Security`, authorization is successful, but when I try to execute a method of one of the classes(Customer, Admin or Cook), it gives *json error 403*:

```java
{
  "timestamp": "2020-05-08T19:48:43.999+0000",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Forbidden",
  "path": "/admin/cooks"
}
```

Please tell me what I did wrong. Where was the mistake.

User:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@ApiModel
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    // Roles
    //
    public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    public static final String ROLE_CUSTOMER = "CUSTOMER";
    public static final String ROLE_COOK = "COOK";
    //


    public User() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }


    // Поля
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    // Методы
    //
    // GrantedAuthority
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    }


    // userName == login (одно и тоже)
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }


    // Во всех флагах стоит TRUE, так как они не используются
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    //
}
```

For example I add only one class Admin:

Admin:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@ApiModel
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class Admin {

    public Admin() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    // Поля

    // name, lastName, login, password берем от класса User через связи;

    @ApiModelProperty
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;


    // Relationships
    //
    @ApiModelProperty
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id") // Join without Admin in User class
    private User user;
}
```

AdminService:

```java
@Service
public class AdminService extends UserService {

    // Поля
    //
    // Injects in setters
    private AdminRepository adminRepository; // Администратор

    private OrderRepository orderRepository; // Заказ

    private CookRepository cookRepository; // Повар

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository; // Заказчик


    // Getters and Setters
    //
    // Делаем inject через сеттеры
    @Autowired
    public void setAdminRepository(AdminRepository adminRepository) {
        this.adminRepository = adminRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setOrderRepository(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCookRepository(CookRepository cookRepository) {
        this.cookRepository = cookRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerRepository(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }


    // Методы
    //
    // Вывод списка всех заказов
    public List<Order> getAllOrders() {
        return orderRepository.findAll();
    }


    // Вывод информации по конкретному заказу
    public Order getOrderInfo(Long id) {
        try {
            return orderRepository.getById(id);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(id);
        }
    }


    // Вывод Повара по ID
    public Cook getCook(Long id) {
        try {
            return cookRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, "COOK");
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(id);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }


    // Изменить карту повара
    public void editCook(Long id, User user, float rating, String aboutCook) {
        Cook cook = cookRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, "COOK");
        try {
            cook.setUser(user);
            cook.setRating(rating);
            cook.setAboutCook(aboutCook);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(id);
        }
    }


    // Вывод всех поваров
    public List<Cook> getAllCooks() {
        return cookRepository.findByUserRole("COOK");
    }


    // Удалить Повара
    public void deleteCook(Long id) {
        Cook cook = cookRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, "COOK");
        try {
            cookRepository.delete(cook);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(id);
        }
    }


    // Вывод всех Заказчиков
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        return customerRepository.findByUserRole("CUSTOMER");
    }


    // Вывод Заказчика по ID
    public Customer getCustomer(Long id) {
        try {
            return customerRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, "CUSTOMER");
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(id);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

AdminController:

```java
@Api(value = "Работа с Админом", tags = {"Администратор"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public class AdminController {

    // Constructor
    //
    // Inject через конструктор
    @Autowired
    public AdminController(AdminRepository adminRepository, AdminService adminService, UserService userService) {
        this.adminRepository = adminRepository;
        this.adminService = adminService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    // Поля
    // All injects into constructor
    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;

    private final AdminService adminService;

    private final UserService userService;


    // Методы
    //
    // GET MAPPING
    //
    // Вывод списка всех заказов
    @GetMapping("/orders")
    List<Order> getAllOrders() {
        return adminService.getAllOrders();
    }


    // Вывод информации по конкретному заказу по ID
    @GetMapping("/order/{id}")
    Order getOrderInfo(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return adminService.getOrderInfo(id);
    }


    // Вывод всех Поваров
    @GetMapping("/cooks")
    List<Cook> getAllCooks() {
        return adminService.getAllCooks();
    }


    // Вывод Повара по ID
    @GetMapping("/cook/{id}")
    Cook getCook(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return adminService.getCook(id);
    }


    // Вывод всех пользователей
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    List<Customer> getAllCustomer() {
        return adminService.getAllCustomers();
    }


    // Вывод Заказчика по ID
    @GetMapping("/customer/{id}")
    Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return adminService.getCustomer(id);
    }


    // POST MAPPING
    //


    // PUT MAPPING
    //
    // Изменяем Повара по ID
    @PutMapping("/edit/cook/{id}")
    void editCook(@PathVariable Long id, User user, @PathVariable float rating, String aboutCook) {
        adminService.editCook(id, user, rating, aboutCook);
    }

    // Поменять пароль
    @PutMapping("/change/password")
    void changePassword(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String newPass) {
        userService.changePassword(login, newPass);
    }


    // DELETE MAPPING
    //
    // Удалить конкретного Повара по ID
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/cook/{id}")
    void removeCook(@PathVariable Long id) {
        adminService.deleteCook(id);
    }
}
```

I use annotation *@RolesAllowed*.

SpringWebConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    // Поля
    //
    private UserService userService;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;



    // Injects in SETTERS
    //
    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }



    // Methods
    //
    // Тут мы переопределяем метод конфигураций
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }


    // Тут мы переопределяем для работы с внешней БД
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }


    // Beans
    //
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }


    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }


    // Возвращаем сервис пользовател для userDetService
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try debugging the user principal object to see what is there. You could set an API to authenticated and print out the object `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`. It's likely your role mapping is off/the roles is empty but they are under the `authorities` instead

Comment: I added a debug screen. I can’t deal with this for 4 days already. You want to say that it would be better if I change `SecurityContextHolder.getContext (). GetAuthentication (). GetPrincipal ()` on your `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` ?

Comment: What is `UserService`, can you paste it here ?

Comment: Can you also paste the exact request (including headers) for which you get reponse 403?

Comment: need to pass ROLE_ADMIN in grunted authority.. i think you pass ADMIN to spring security grunted authority in your userService class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this problem, add the following to the `WebSecurityConfig` class in the `configure` method at the very beginning:

```java
http
.cors().disable()
.csrf().disable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change`@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")` to `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")` for it to match the conventional prefix of role names (the one you used in `User::getAuthorities`).

Comment: Дмитрий, может быть у меня отсутствует SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() ?